# malloc: *** error for object 0x10003b3c4: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++

I'm new on programming C++, please be patient :) My problem is that the model (a DGVM) runs until the end, but the last message I receive is "malloc: *** error for object 0x10003b3c4: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". The debugger points to this:

```
clTreePop::~clTreePop() {free(Trees);}
```

The debugger points to `free(Trees)`and gives the message: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)". What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

The part of the code that may be important for this question:

```
void clTreePop::addFirstTree( double init_mass)
{
   clTree Tree( init_mass, -1. , pop_size_, count_trees_);

   Trees = (clTree *) malloc(sizeof(clTree));

   Trees[0] = Tree;
   pop_size_ ++;
   new_born_ ++;
   count_trees_ ++;
   root_biomass_  += Tree.getBr();
   stem_biomass_  += Tree.getBS();
   leaf_biomass_  += Tree.getBl();
   canopy_area_   += Tree.getCanopyArea();
   gc_weighted_   += Tree.getGc();
   max_height_    += MyMax(max_height_,Tree.getHeight());
   basal_area_    += Tree.getStemArea();

   return; }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in C++ You don't need to use malloc, as the allocation can be done in diffrent, better, and if not, at least easier ways. Malloc is an old, low level, C (not C++) way. Try using

```
clTree *Trees = new clTree;
```

The code You copied does not show the situation fully, althrough what I can see is that instead of

```
Trees = (clTree *) malloc(sizeof(clTree));
```

You should use:

```
clTree *Trees = (clTree *) malloc(sizeof(clTree));
```

This way You create a pointer to which Then You attach structure, which You allocated.

The error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" indicates some kind of incopatibility in between Your code and the architecture of Your computer (processor, system, etc.). I do not know the matter, but I think it is caused by the mistake I listed before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both codes you suggested but then it pointed to other errors...I guess the problem is the incompatibility you said, because the model is old but it worked well before I updated the operational system (MacOS Sierra) and the Xcode (8.2(8C38))...